# user control button click in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have user control file cust_list.ascx

i have added this control to my aspx page.
have two buttons in my aspx page..

during page_load I displayed 5 controls..

when i click on next button.it will show next 5 controls...i have previous button too.

my problem is when in click on button which is in user control after next button click the page set back to initial state.which is having situation same as when the first time page was loaded.but button_click in user control doesnt fire.

Comment: maybe you should use ajax to not render all the page when the button is clicked

Comment: sorry cust_list.ascx is user control

Answer (score 0):

The below link might help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9080243/546033

There instead of `HtmlGenericControl` use your control like `Button`

Or else you need to load the user-control at `Page_Load` OR `Page_Init` so that the control events get registered like

```
Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
createControls();
}
```

make sure to keep the function call out of `if(!isPostBack)` as it wont be able to click after postback.

hope this helps you....